# how to check given date exist in month or not?

Tags: c#, linq, date

I have a combo Box In which I made a collection of dates from 1 to 31
and also I have a checklist box in which I made a collection of month
from Jan to Dec.
Now I have to put validation on date that if user select 31 and select month Jan, Feb, Mar then a message popup and
inform them 31 does not exist in February

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what code u did

Comment: rather than chastise user on making an invalid choice, simply don't present as an option. i.e. Feb should show 1 - 28 in non-leap years.

Comment: @Boss: Just curious: Why don't you use a `date-picker` + `jquery`?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: It's not clear that this is a web app to start with...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Oops. Ya you are right. Thought it was some web app. Sorry

Comment: Well, if it's a WinForms app, he could use a [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx).  If it's a WebForms app, he could use a `date-picker` or an [`AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/calendar/calendar.aspx).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want the [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
public bool IsDateValid(int year, int month, int day) {
    return day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
}
```

I'm assuming that the `year` and `month` values will always be sensible, and that `day` will always be greater than or equal to 1. You could easily add argument validation. I'm also assuming that you already have the month as a number, rather than just a name. (Differentiate between the display format of a value and the underlying value.)

Note that you'll need a year picker, otherwise you won't know whether February 29th is valid or not.

(And as Mitch says, it would be better to design a UI where invalid choices simply don't appear, ideally.)

Comment: +1. `A great application is which doesn't allow its users to do invalid operations`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact scenario that I use when suggesting someone should use a `switch` with creatively placed `break` statements.

Something like:

```
public bool IsValidDay (string nameOfMonth, int day)
{
    int total_days_in_month;

    switch ( nameOfMonth )
    {
        case "jan":
        case "mar":
                    case "may":
        case "jul":
        case "aug":
        case "oct":
        case "dec":
            total_days_in_month = 31;
            break;
        case "apr":
        case "jun":
        case "sep":
        case "nov":
            total_days_in_month = 30;
            break;
        case "feb":
        default:
            total_days_in_month = 28;
            break;
    }

    return ( day <= total_days_in_month );
}
```

Comment: That doesn't take leap years into account... and I'd argue it's not the best place to use a switch statement, to be honest.

Comment: @Flater: How are you gonna return for a leap year?

Comment: Point taken. However, leap years are not mentioned in the question, so I didn't figure taking them into account because I have no idea if it's pertinent to the question. I don't even see a field to input the year in OP's screenshot. However, I did not know about the `DaysInMonth`method of `DateTime`. Infinitely easier.

Comment: @Flater: True, I hadn't spotted that - that's a failure in the UI though, I'd say :)

Comment: I see this question is quite old, I was wondering though in a situation where you have input in the form of Day/Month (where the year isn't available or mentioned) this solution will work fine except I would use 29 days for Feb/default in the switch statement then...